# Conditional data binding in Angular with piped (translate) variables

Tags: angular, data-binding, conditional-statements, angular-translate

Hey stackoverflow / Angular Community!

I have a little question about data-binding on components.
The `[value]` on my component can have two different strings/labels as value. Since the app knows more languages I am using the translate-pipe for this.
The code-excerpt is probably very self-explanatory.

```
<my-component [value]="bool1 ? {{'GLOBAL.YES' | translate }} : {{'GLOBAL.NO' | translate }}"></my-component>
```

Leads to:
**Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected**

It feels like there is a syntax thing, I am missing out on. Tried a lot of different combinations. When I try `value` without the brackets I end up having the whole string starting with 'bool1 ? ...' as value (what definetly makes sense).

Maybe someone knows how to fix this?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Change to this
<my-component [value]="bool1 ? 'GLOBAL.YES' | translate  : 'GLOBAL.NO' | translate "></my-component>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do interpolation in property binding.
You can use a method that [JFPicard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4641455/jfpicard) showed.

Or, if you really need to do this in template, do this:

```
<my-component [value]="(bool1 ? 'GLOBAL.YES' : 'GLOBAL.NO') | translate"></my-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ngx-translate, you can probably do it in the .ts like this:

```
<my-component [value]="getTranslation(bool1)" />
```

And in your ts

```
  private getTranslation(value: boolean): string {  
    return value ? translate.instant("GLOBAL.YES"): translate.instant("GLOBAL.NO")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as following way

```
<component [value]="(bool1 ? 'GLOBAL.YES' : 'GLOBAL.NO') | translate"></component>
```